# Error using png in User Control

Tags: javascript, user-controls, genexus

I'm doing an user control, and I want to use some images that I use like this:

```
    // image loader
    var imageURLs = [];
    var imagesOK = 0;
    var imgs = [];
    imageURLs.push("shapes/isit.png");
    imageURLs.push("shapes/ec.png");
    imageURLs.push("shapes/bc.png");
    imageURLs.push("shapes/bb.png");
    imageURLs.push("shapes/io.png");
    loadAllImages();

    function loadAllImages() {
      for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function () {
          imagesOK++;
          if (imagesOK == imageURLs.length) {
            start();
          }
        };
        img.id = i;
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
      }
    }
```

this code is in show method.

But I have this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL                          isit.png:1
```

(the same error for each png)

I have checked if the images are in the knowledgebase directory, and they are.

And after that errors I also have this errors:

```
GET http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Id899a095c574c049b25f760a574de3016/shapes/isit.png 404 (Not Found)         Test1Render.js:92
```

(the same error for each png)

But I think this error is a consequence of the previous errors.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

[image]

[image]

**Edit2:**

[image]

Comment: It seems that Deploy To Cloud hasn't uploaded the UserControl files. Try deleting 'gxlastransfer.zip' from your Web folder and execute F5 from GeneXus. Are you sure that those files are inside folder shapes?

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloGallotti. About the images yes, I'm sure they are inside the folder (in edit). I tried the execute F5 after deleted 'gxlastransfer.zip', and I did it twice, but without success, I still have the errors. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! 
The path to the images are Test1\shapes\bb.png. 
You are missing "Test1".

Ex: 
http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Id899a095c574c049b25f760a574de3016/test1/shapes/isit.png

```
imageURLs.push("test1/shapes/isit.png");
imageURLs.push("test1/shapes/ec.png");
imageURLs.push("test1/shapes/bc.png");
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can access the images, and use them in the webpanel, but I still have the first errors (Edit2). Do you know why?